Getting an error in SQL group by function
Given the two tables shown below, write a query to display the comparison result (higher/lower/same) of the average salary of employees in a department to the company’s average salary.
Table: salary



id
employee_id
amount
pay_date




1
1
9000
2017-03-31


2
2
6000
2017-03-31


3
3
10000
2017-03-31


4
1
7000
2017-02-28


5
2
6000
2017-02-28


6
3
8000
2017-02-28



The employee_id column refers to the employee_id in the following table employee:



employee_id
department_id




1
1


2
2


3
2



So for the sample data above, the result is:



pay_month
department_id
comparison




2017-03
1
higher


2017-03
2
lower


2017-02
1
same


2017-02
2
same



Below is the solution that I tried:
WITH comp_avg AS 
(
    SELECT 
        date_format(pay_date, '%Y-%m') AS months, 
        AVG(amount) AS avg_amt
    FROM 
        salary 
    GROUP BY 
        date_format(pay_date, '%Y-%m')
)
SELECT 
    date_format(s.pay_date, '%Y-%m') AS months, 
    e.department_id, 
    AVG(s.amount) AS avg_amount,
    CASE 
        WHEN AVG(s.amount) > (SELECT avg_amt FROM comp_avg WHERE date_format(s.pay_date, '%Y-%m') = comp_avg.months) THEN 'higher'
        WHEN AVG(s.amount) < (SELECT avg_amt FROM comp_avg WHERE date_format(s.pay_date, '%Y-%m') = comp_avg.months) THEN 'lower'
        ELSE 'same'
    END AS comparison
FROM 
    salary s
JOIN 
    employee e ON s.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY 
    date_format(s.pay_date, '%Y-%m'), e.department_id;

Explanation:

I first found the year-month wise average salary of the company and stored it in a cte
Computed year-month and department wise average salary and used the above cte results for that year-month and compared and showed the output.

But am getting this error:

Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mycompiler.s.pay_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Am not sure, where am going wrong as the subquery is working perfectly fine when am running it separately.

Which database are you using? I removed the tag spamming.

Logically your sql makes sense and, unless I'm overlooking something, feels like it should work. My guess is that with the addition of the correlated subquery inside a GROUP BY, your DB is just getting tangled up and can't figure out how to execute. Instead consider joining in your CTE in your FROM clause and then rewriting your Case expression. Simplifying the logic away from a correlated subquery should help.

@TheImpaler, Thanks for editing the post. Will take care of it next time.
Am using MySql - was trying it on the below link
https://www.mycompiler.io/new/mysql?fork=LfrBbPEt5H5

@JNevill, I tried using inner join, its working using that but using subquery in the case statements, its failing. Got it, maybe this is the case, its confused between the GROUP BY in the cte and its usage it in the CASE WHEN statement.

I think  @JNevill is correct regarding the subqueries in the case. I'd do the group into another CTE and then do the comparison.

@StephenWrighton are you talking about the group by in the main query ?? - GROUP BY
date_format(s.pay_date, '%Y-%m'), e.department_id;
this one. I didn't get you.

@RaghavMittal - Apologies I was unclear. I meant the group of SAlary/Employees be turned into a distinct CTE, and then you can use that to compare the Average amounts to comp_avg.

Not related to the error, but you can use aliases in GROUP BY. So use GROUP BY months instead of GROUP BY date_format(s.pay_date, '%Y-%m').
